# Calculate reflection matrix given normal vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reflection

Let $A$ be origin plane in ${\Bbb R}^3$ given normal vector $n = (x,y,z)$. $T = {\Bbb R}^3 \to {\Bbb R}^3$.

How do I go about calculating the reflection matrix $T$?

Given is the following formula

$$ T(v) = v-2\frac{v \cdot n}{n \cdot n} n $$

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose some basis, for example the standard basis: $e_1,e_2,e_3$, and then find the representative matrix. 
For example: 
Let's find the reflection matrix for the normal: $n=(x,y,z)=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0,-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$.
we will choose the standard basis, and:
$T(v)=v-2\frac{v⋅n}{n⋅n}n=v-2n<v,n>.$
$T(e_1)=e_1-2n<e_1,n>=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}-2⋅\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\0\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\end{pmatrix}<\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\0\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})\end{pmatrix}>=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ 
similarly, $T(e_2)=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}, T(e_3)=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$. Which means, that the reflection matrix would be:
$T=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&0&0\end{pmatrix}.\square$